# Google pixel ReactiveNetwork wifi change event is received in 30 sec delay

Tags: android, networking, pixel, reactive

I am using ReactiveNetwork library.
This is my code that listening to wifi connectivity changes.

```
ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity(activity?.applicationContext)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .filter(ConnectivityPredicate.hasType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    logWarning("###### change network = $it")
                },{ })
```

I am testing the code on different devices and its works but in google pixel, I am receiving the wifi connectivity change event in 30 seconds delay.

Someone know why?